# Angular - is filtering responses in http interceptor a good idea?

Tags: angular, interceptor

I've made an http interceptor in which I'm filtering `HttpEvent` to get only `HttpResponse`. It looks like that:

```
return next.handle(requestToSend).pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
  map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => this.handleResponse(event)),
  catchError(error => this.handleErrors(error))
);
```

And here is my question: Is it a good idea to filter responses to get only `HttpResponse`? Won't it break anything, like e.g. Web Sockets? Does it actually work like some kind of firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interceptor only handles requests made by the `HttpClient`. So it should not break anything related to other HTTP request like websockets, as long as you don't use the `HttpClient` to perform those requests.

Regarding the filtering of the requests, it makes sense, because there are [different kind of events](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent) that can be returned by the [`handle`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHandler#handle) method. But in the following `map()` function the event is strictly typed as `HttpResponse`.